# Where can I find a database that contains all the airline companies with their alliances and if they are low cost or not

Tags: data-request, geospatial, transportation

I am looking for a database that contains all the airline companies alongside the alliances that they belong to, and if they are low-cost or not.

So far I found this [Airport, airline and route data](https://openflights.org/data.html) but it doesn't seem to give the information on whether the compagnies are low cost and to which alliance they belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FaLabel%20%3Fis_lowcost%20%3FaffiliateLabel%20%3Fiata%20where%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fa%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ1875615%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28%28EXISTS%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ190915%20%7D%29%20AS%20%3Fis_lowcost%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP749%20%3Fparent%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP361%20%3Fwhole%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP127%20%3Fowner%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP114%20%3Falliance%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP229%20%3Fiata%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28%20COALESCE%28%3Falliance%2C%20%3Fparent%2C%20%3Fparent%2C%20%3Fowner%29%20AS%20%3Faffiliate%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20order%20by%20DESC%28%3Fis_lowcost%29) this query on Wikidata:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?aLabel ?is_lowcost ?affiliateLabel ?iata where {
  ?a wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1875615 .
  BIND ((EXISTS {?a wdt:P31 wd:Q190915 }) AS ?is_lowcost )
  OPTIONAL {?a wdt:P749 ?parent}
  OPTIONAL {?a wdt:P361 ?whole}
  OPTIONAL {?a wdt:P127 ?owner}
  OPTIONAL {?a wdt:P114 ?alliance}
  OPTIONAL {?a wdt:P229 ?iata}
  BIND ( COALESCE(?alliance, ?parent, ?parent, ?owner) AS ?affiliate)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
  } ORDER BY DESC(?is_lowcost)
```

The values in the `affiliateLabel` column are coalesced from the values of these  properties:

- [parent organization](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P749),
- [part of](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P361),
- [owner](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P127),
- [airline alliance](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P114).

Try [this](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FaLabel%20%3Fis_lowcost%20%3FaffiliateLabel%20%3FparentLabel%20%3FwholeLabel%20%3FownerLabel%20%3FallianceLabel%20%3Fiata%20where%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fa%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ1875615%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28%28EXISTS%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ190915%20%7D%29%20AS%20%3Fis_lowcost%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP749%20%3Fparent%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP361%20%3Fwhole%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP127%20%3Fowner%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP114%20%3Falliance%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fa%20wdt%3AP229%20%3Fiata%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20order%20by%20DESC%28%3Fis_lowcost%29) query, if you want to get the values of these properties separated.

As to low-coster status, the data is obviously incomplete. For instanse, [wd:Q18398469](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q18398469) is definitely a low-coster.